# how to add/create new gestures in oracle jdeveloper 11.1.2.3?

Tags: android-emulator, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, android-gesture, oracle-fusion-middleware

edited:

I am new to Oracle Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3, can any one please tell me, how can I use the gestures created in gesture builder application (in emulator) in my own application ?

I found this link [ http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/ ] relating to what I am trying but I am not able to use it or implement it in Jdeveloper.

also can I run the code in the above link in eclipse & export it to Jdeveloper & use it there ?

please guide me on this...

===========================================================================

What I am trying, is to get some action done in applications by using different gestures other than swipe-right, swipe-left, swipe-down, swipe-up & tap-hold gestures which are already present in software (setPropertyListener - type attribute).

for example if I make a cross mark gesture on list item then it should get cancelled or if I make a tick mark gesture on list item then it should be accepted.

so, is there any way by which I can add new gestures to the application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an amx:actionListener tag to the component that needs to support a gesture and set the type attribute on it.
Example here: http://lucbors.blogspot.com/2013/02/adf-mobile-implementing-pull-to-refresh.html

Comment: correct me if I am wrong...
what I am getting from the link is that the code should be somewhat like this: 

<amx:commandLink id="cmdlink" text="Swipe Down to call bean method">

  <amx:actionListener binding="#{GestureBean.SwipeDownMethod}" type="swipeDown"/>

</amx:commandLink>

if it is so, I have already tried that & it is working fine...

Q> My question is can I add my own new gestures in the type attribute ? (other than: swipeDown, swipeUp, swipeRight, swipeLeft, tapHold)

Q> Can we use the gestures made in "gesture builder app" (in emulator) in this type attribute ?